# In selection sort, descending array's performance is faster than ascending array. why?

Tags: c, algorithm, selection-sort

I ran selection sort algorithm with a sorted array(ascending order) and a unsorted array(decending order) in C visual studio.
The result was performance of a unsorted array is faster than one of a sorted array in large size.

I think it's very ridiculous. Doesn't selection sort always take constant time depends on array size?
Why is this??

This is selectionsort. And I ran this with n = 100,000 to 1,000,000. I increased it by 100,000 for every run.

```
int main() {
    int array[1000000]; //1,000,000
    int i = 100000; //100,000
    int n = 100000; //100,000
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        insert_ascending(array, n); //stuff elements in ascending order
        //time check
        sort(array, n);

        insert_decending(array, n); //stuff elements in descending order
        //time check
        sort(array, n);

        n += i;
    }
}
void selectionSort(int *list, const int n)
{
    int i, j, indexMin, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        indexMin = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] < list[indexMin])
            {
                indexMin = j;
            }
        }
        temp = list[indexMin];
        list[indexMin] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `Doesn't selection sort always take constant time depends on array size?` - [no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/11683).

Comment: For any meaningful response to this question would it not make sense that a person would need to see a minimal representation of the implementation?  Post a [mcve]

Comment: @ryyker but the array is not unsorted, OP is just using a wrong term - instead it is *descending order*. Granted, the duplicate isn't necessarily a correct one here, but, until OP proves otherwise let's assume that it is.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry. I was confused about using the term. And I read the duplicate about branch prediction. I think in case of ascending array, the if-statement always false. About descending one, this always true. So in selection sort, I think this have nothing to do. Is there something I must know about this question?

Comment: @Geum if you'd make this into a fullblown program, including making the test arrays, then it would actually be a *good question*.

Comment: Hmm I guess this is answerable...

Comment: it is somewhat reproduceable

Comment: I did it with GCC and I can see the same difference, @ryyker the most amazing thing is that the descending array writes to memory *way more*, but it is still faster :?

Comment: And this with unoptimized. With optimized, the sorted was faster... I still cannot quite explain :'D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added the main function. And I knew that if we use "volatile" int i, j, indexMin, temp  in binary search function, a asceding array is faster than descending one.

Comment: I get 2680713 A, 2576229 D, 2695650 A, 2632687 D, even though descending does write the new index to *memory* every time :D

Comment: @Antti - your assertion that editing the code into the question in would make it a _good_  question is true.  Maybe even worth an up-click.  (If you haven't already done so.)

Comment: There is a cache effect. When descending, the target cell has a higher chance of beeing present in the cache. The ascending walk has a similar cache trashing effect, but the target cell has a higher chance of **not** being cached.

Comment: @wildplasser hmm, not sure if it alone will cause the 4 percent difference that I am seeing, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes my 0.02 €.

I could see a 4 % speed difference favouring the descending array over ascending array in unoptimized code on GCC. My hypothesis is that it is caused by the

```
if (list[j] < list[indexMin]) {
    indexMin = j;
}
```

being compiled to

```
        ...
        jge     .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
.L4:
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
```

i.e. it is not a branch prediction failure - for the ascending case the `jge` **always** branches, and for the descending case it **never** branches. The `jge` taking the branch does take more cycles than actually updating the index variable in cache.

Of course, if you compile with optimization enabled, the ascending code wins.